# Processing and splitting large files with Java 8

Tags: java, file, split, java-8, nio

I'm new to Java 8 and I have just started using the NIO package for file-handling. I need help in how to process large files--varying from 100,000 lines to 1,000,000 lines per file--by transforming each line into a specific format and writing the formatted lines to new files. The new file(s) generated must only contain a maximum of 100,000 lines per file. So:

- if I have a 500,000-line file for processing, I must transform those
  lines and distribute and print them on 5 new files.
- if I have a 745,000-line file for processing, I must transform those
  lines and print them on 8 new files.

I'm having a hard time figuring out an approach that will efficiently utilize the new features of Java 8. I've started out with determining the number of new files to be generated based on the line count of the large file, and then creating those new empty files:

```
Path largFile = Path.get("path\to\file");
long recordCount = Files.lines(file).count();
int maxRecordOfNewFiles = 100000;
int numberOfNewFiles =  1;
if (recordCount > maxRecordOfNewFiles) {
    numberOfNewFiles = Math.toIntExact(recordCount / maxRecordOfNewFiles);
if (Math.toIntExact(recordCount % maxRecordOfNewFiles) > 0) {
    numberOfNewFiles ++;
}
}

IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numberOfNewFiles).forEach((i) 
    -> {
        try {
            Path newFile = Paths.get("path\to\newFiles\newFile1.txt");
                        Files.createFile(cdpFile);
         } catch (IOException iOex) {
         }
        });
```

But as I go through the the lines of the `largeFile` through the `Files.lines(largeFile).forEach(())` capability, I got lost on how to proceed with formatting the first 100,000 lines and then determining the first of the new files and printing them on that file, and then the second batch of 100,000 to the second new file, and so on.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: You may just start reading and formating line per line until you reach 100k and then save the new *part* file.

Comment: @WoozyCoder, hi! :) That's basically what I've said on the last part of my post. Haha. My question is how do I do that using Java 8? Code snippets would be really helpful. :)

Comment: You could use an `List<String>` to store the formatted data (don't really know what you mean with this, though). When you reach 100k or the end of the file, create the *part* file, save the data contained in the `ArrayList<String>` and continue with the next bunch of lines. Here the thing is, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @WoozyCoder tried your idea and it works with smaller files. Not sure how it'll fare with large files though. I'll also be trying Tunaki and Jatin's answers to test which of your ideas is more fast and memory-efficient, since I will be using this on a production scale environment. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you start conceiving batch processes, I think you should consider using a framework specialized in that. You may want to handle restarts, scheduling... [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) is very good for that and already provides what you want: [`MultiResourceItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemWriter.html) that writes to multiple files with max lines per file and [`FlatFileItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html) to read data from a file.

---

In this case, what you want is to loop over each line of an input file and write a transformation of each line in multiple output files.

One way to do that would be to create a Stream over the lines of the input file, map each line and send it to a custom writer. This custom writer would implement the logic of switching writer when it has reached the maximum number of lines per file.

In the following code `MyWriter` opens a `BufferedWriter` to a file. When the `maxLines` is reached (a multiple of it), this writer is closed and another one is opened, incrementing `currentFile`. This way, it is transparent for the reader that we're writing to multiple files.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (
        MyWriter writer = new MyWriter(10);
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("path/to/file"));
    ) {
        lines.map(l -> /* do transformation here */ l).forEach(writer::write);
    }
}

private static class MyWriter implements AutoCloseable {

    private long count = 0, currentFile = 1, maxLines = 0;
    private BufferedWriter bw = null;

    public MyWriter(long maxLines) {
        this.maxLines = maxLines;
    }

    public void write(String line) {
        try {
            if (count % maxLines == 0) {
                close();
                bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("path/to/newFiles/newFile" + currentFile++ + ".txt"));
            }
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();
            count++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (bw != null) bw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tunaki! :) I will be trying out your answer, and I'll give update.. :) I'm kind of having second thoughts using another framework, since I want to try how Java 8 alone fares with the problem. Do you think using the Spring Batch will be more efficient instead of Java's native libraries in terms of memory and speed? :)

Comment: @BubeyReb It isn't strictly a question of efficiency, Spring Batch just provides prebuilt tools for batching processes (you can read its into [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/)), like transaction management, job processing statistics, job restart, skip, and resource management... So if this something you want to have (and you intend to write multiple batches), you can keep it in mind ;). It is definitely too much for this particular simple example.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand in question. A simple way can be:

```
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("H:\\Docs\\log.txt")));
Pair<Integer, BufferedWriter> ans = buff.lines().reduce(new Pair<Integer, BufferedWriter>(0, null), (count, line) -> {
    try {
        BufferedWriter w;
        if (count.getKey() % 1000 == 0) {
            if (count.getValue() != null) count.getValue().close();
            w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("f" + count.getKey() + ".txt")));
        } else w = count.getValue();
        w.write(line + "\n"); //do something
        return new Pair<>(count.getKey() + 1, w);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}, (x, y) -> {
    throw new RuntimeException("Not supproted");
});
ans.getValue().close();
```

Comment: Hi @Jatin! What scares me about Java 8 is how complex it is and how it makes code super hard to read for some developers like me. Looking at your answer, it was kind of hard to understand what the your code was trying to accomplish. <br/> Tried to research the `.reduce()` function and that confused me even more. :( Also tried running your code but `BufferedReader` doesn't take a `FileReader` as a valid constructor argument. That goes the same with `BufferedWriter`. <br/> The purpose of `ans.getValue().close()` is also confusing. Maybe you can try breaking down your answer?

Comment: @BubeyReb That code compiles and runs fine. BufferedReader does take  Reader as argument. So FileReader is valid constructor argument. Same is true with BufferedWriter which takes Writer.

So the idea is: For each line, if the count has not crossed 1000, write it using the writer available. If it has, then reset the count, create a new writer and carry it forward and do close the previous writer. Keep repeating this process.
Now in the end, close the last remaining writer.

Comment: By the way you also need to import javafx.util.Pair. Well you could use someother Pair class. I needed a tuple and this felt ok.